# using any() in return with for loop

Tags: python, return, return-value

I faced with a usage of any() like this:

```
return any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)
```

When I checked, any() returns True if any element of an iterable is True.So i think that if any() checks any element of an iterable, why do we use for loop? it already checks every element in it..

Another thing I didn't understand with this syntax is that what does it do in for loop? it is at the end of the line, and there is nothing after it..

Comment: Try printing: `[node.state == state for node in self.frontier]` to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: `return any(self.frontier)` wouldn't check the `state` attribute of each `node` is why you need to be explicit,

Comment: This a generator syntax, look abut list comprehensio too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example you might see the difference:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Node = namedtuple('Node', ['state'])

state = 2
frontier = [Node(1), Node(1)]

print("Any frontier:", any(frontier))
print("Any state:", any(node.state == state for node in frontier))
```

The output is:

```
Any frontier: True
Any state: False
```

From the `any` documentation: `Return True if any element of the iterable is true.`

In the first case the iterable is the **`frontier`** and element in the iterable is the element in the frontier array.

In the second case the iterable is **the list of comparisons between node.state and state** and element is the result of this comparison.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the built-in function `any(iterable)` does roughly the same as:

```
def any(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True
    return False
```

Regarding your particular case, you actually have an iterable of nodes, so you can't use `any(self.frontier)` directly. What you really need is a way to convert your original iterable into another one where each element is compared with the given state. And Python provides a compact syntax for such kinds of transformations called generator expressions. Thus, `node.state == state for node in self.frontier` is just an easy way to convert your initial iterable of nodes (i.e. `self.frontier`) into an iterable of booleans.